# Fourier series of $\{x\}$ (the fractional part of $x$ ) is weird: "$\{1\} = 0.5$"

Tags: fourier-series

If $x(t) = \{t\}$ (the fractional part of $t$), then the Fourier series of $x(t)$ is $$\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2\pi nt)}{n}$$

My question is why $x(1) = 0.5$ (using the Fourier series) and not $0$, as expected?

Notice that $x(t) = \{t\} = t - \lfloor t \rfloor$, so $x(1) = 1 - \lfloor 1 \rfloor = 1 - 1 = 0$.

However, with the Fourier series, it gives $0.5$ because

$$\begin{split}
x(1) &= \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin(2\pi n\cdot1)}{n}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi} \cdot 0\\
&= \frac{1}{2} - 0\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{split}
$$

Is it only true for non-integer values, e.g., is it true for $\sqrt 2$, but not for the number $1$?

Comment: To recollection, the Fourier series of a suitably-nice function can differ from the original function on a set of measure zero, and commonly at discontinuities (as the integers are for the periodic extension of the fractional part), so this result shouldn't be unexpected.

Comment: Because $\lim_{x\to1-}\{x\}=0$ and $\lim_{x\to0+}\{x\}=1.$  Remember, any finite Fourier series sum is continuous, but $\{x\}$ is discontinuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fractional function is continuous everywhere but the integers on the real line. At a continuous point, Fourier series converge nicely to the value of the function, but at a discontinuous point, Fourier series converge to the average of the right and left limits at the point, which gives $\frac{0+1}{2}=0.5$ in your case.

In general, Fourier series is not necessarily convergent. Or Convergence might be in another sense. Pointwise convergence is rare.